# Invoke specific function before every numpy method

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to program this library where I want to call a certain function every time a numpy function is called.

So basically instead of writing a code like this:

```
import numpy as np

class MyLibClassObj(np.ndarray):
      pass

def zeros(a, b):
    if a is not instance(a, np.ndarray):
         a = MyLibClassObj(a)
    return np.zeros(a) + b

--------------------------------
x = zeros(2, b)
```

to somewhat like this:

```
import mylib.numpy as np
x = np.zeros(2, b)
```

So I do not want to create a function in my library to replace every function in numpy. I think I am missing something here either from numpy docs or python docs that will automatically wrap(?) a function around numpy functions in general.

I know I can use lambda functions to create a wrapper but then I will have to create a wrapper for each and every function in numpy.

Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that's the best/cleanest way of doing this, but you can use a class to delegate and decorate functions from the numpy module. This can be done on the flight the first time you call a function (then we can set this function as a new method of our class):

```py
def numpy_decorator(numpy_function):

    def decorated_numpy_function(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"You just called {numpy_function.__name__}({args}, {kwargs})")
        return numpy_function(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated_numpy_function


class DefinitelyNotNumpy:
    def __init__(self, numpy_module):
        self.np = numpy_module

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if not name.startswith('_'):
            attr = numpy_decorator(getattr(self.np, name))
            setattr(self, name, attr)
            return attr
```

Which you can then use like this:

```py
>>> dtnp = DefinitlyNotNumpy(np)
>>> dtnp.zeros(5)
You just called zeros((5,), {})
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

You could also pass the decorator to `DefinitlyNotNumpy` and then call `dtnp = DefinitlyNotNumpy(np, numpy_decorator)`.